# SELECT SQL data based on date, fill month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

I'm selecting year, month and net sales from invoice table. The problem is that if there's no data under specific month, there will be no rows for that month. Can you help me? Net sales should be zero if there is not any data.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, date) as 'year', 
    DATEPART(month, date) as 'month', 
    SUM(netsales) as netsales 
FROM invoice 
WHERE 
    date >= '2015-01-01' 
    AND date <= '2016-12-31' 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(year, date), 
    DATEPART(month, date)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `calendar` table and `left join`

```
;with calendar as
(
select cast('2015-01-01' as date) as dates -- start date
union all
select dateadd(mm,1,dates) from cte where dates < '2016-12-31' -- end date
)

SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, c.dates) as 'year', 
    DATEPART(month, c.dates) as 'month', 
    SUM(netsales) as netsales 
FROM calendar C left join invoice i on c.dates = cast(i.[date] as date)
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(year, date), 
    DATEPART(month, date)
```

I have generates dates on the fly using `Recursive CTE`,  but I will always suggest to create a calendar table physically and use it in such queries

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach.  Since a lot of companies need reports based on calendar months, I think it's useful to have a table of just months (start date, end date, number of days, calendar year, month number) as well.